# Ajax загрузка файлов

Tags: ajax, php

Фрагмент скрипта мультизагрузки файлов. Тут отправляются заголовки:

```
        self.xhr.open("POST", params.url);

    var boundary = "xxxxxxxxx";
    self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary="+boundary);
    self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    var body = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='"+(params.fieldName || 'file')+"'; filename='" + params.file.name + "'\r\n";
    body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    body += self.reader.result + "\r\n";
    body += "--" + boundary + "--";
```

Как в php сохранить файл, если в массиве `$_FILES` пусто?

Answer (score 1):

Не так давно на другом ресурсе спрашивали или такие возможно, поэтому делал [пример](http://sh.s.wap3.com.ua/ta/) мультиаплоад (несколько файлов за раз) на ajax

Думаю поможет. Естественно броузер должен поддерживать FileAPI

Comment: Интересно)

Comment: ага  FileAPI под ie делается(((

Comment: мне вот этот скрипт приккрутить надо 
http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/ui/html5-drag-n-drop-file-upload.html 

не могу разобраться как сохранять файлы.....

Comment: FileApi подерживается FireFox, Chrome, Opera(вроде) про остальные не в курсе. Если вы будете использовать тот js скрипт, который приведен в примере, то сохранение ничем не будет отличатся от традиционного способа сохранения файлов на стороне сервера

Comment: Ну нету его в массиве $_FILES где мне его взять он грузит кудато показывает 100%, а куда сохраняет черт его знает...

Comment: где нету ? На той url что я вам дал ничего не выводит после аплоада ?

вижу 2 реквеста:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1

и 

Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.52

Не уверен что в FF4 реализовано FileApi поставьте последнюю версию хрома либо FF

Comment: http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/ui/html5-drag-n-drop-file-upload.html

я про этот говорю вот там ничего нету кроме имени загружаемого файла в теле запроса

fileUpload:player.png